# can`t import kamon-play-26 using SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, kamon

I updated my play to 2.6.0. I have a kamon dependency but sbt can't resolve this dependency.

Did anyone encounter this problem too?

Below is my libraryDependencies in the build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies +=
    Seq(
        ws,
      "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0",
      "io.kamon" %% "kamon-play-26" % "0.6.7"
    )
```

But I get a below error as kamon-play-26 not found...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kamon for Play 2.6 is available for Scala 2.11 and 2.12 with:

```
"io.kamon" %% "kamon-play-2.6" % "0.6.8"
```

Note the period in `2.6`.

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the kamon repositories in maven reveals that there is no kamon-play-26 package.

The github page https://github.com/kamon-io/kamon-play indicates that it does exist however. Perhaps its been pulled because the build is failing. Compile your own package from source, perhaps?

Comment: "Compile your own package from source" what do you mean by that..?